# how to access api in blackberry 10 using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry 10. I am developing an app using html5 and javascript via phonegap.I am unable to fetch the data from the api when i run the application in ripple emulator. Unexpectedly i am getting xmlhttp status -> 0.

when i hit the api url on browser it works fine. Don't know what is exact problem.

Please assist me how to access api in blackberry10?

I am attaching my code here.

HTML code :

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <div>
            <div class="choose-city-head-A">
                <span ><img src="images/m.png" height="70%" style="margin-top:12px;margin-left:45%;" /></span>
                <span style="float:right; margin-top:25px; margin-right:20px;"><img src="images/close.png" height="40%" /></span>
                <span style=" float:right;margin-right:20px; margin-top:25px;"><img src="images/help.png" height="40%" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="choose-city-head-B">
                <h2> Choose City </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="home_data" ></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="choose-city-head-A" data-position="fixed">
        <img src="images/prev_button.png" style="margin-left:90px;" />
        <img src="images/favourities.png" style="margin-left:60px;" />
        <img src="images/sms.png" style="margin-left:60px;" />
        <img src="images/next.png" style="margin-left:60px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript code :

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

function showHome()
{
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "url", true);
//  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xmlhttp.status); //status i am receiving is 0
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                var responsexml=xmlhttp.responseText;
                var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct..

I have also faced this problem ealier
Try to install Emulator again..Hope it will works as it worked for me...!!

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Vedank. It worked for me too.I was searching the code to access the api but re installing the emulator worked for me.